# Listing events from today and being able to step forwards and backwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

Im trying to build a simple event app in rails. The events have a date and a name. 
I want the index view to list 10 events from "today" and on. 
Then it should be possible to step forward/backwards in time and list the next/previous 10 events.

"Next" => Step forward in time by 10 events.

"Previous" => Step backwards in time by 10 events.

I dont know how I should tackle this problem. I have had a look at the will_paginate gem. But there Im only able to list the events from today and step forward.

Comment: Either you calculate the offset of today in a query listing all event chronologically, or you will have to code your own pagination. And with the offset, you will have only p=1/10 of having your today events starting at the first entry.

Comment: Ok, thats how I did it. I calculated the offset of today.